# Selenium WebDriverWait returning exception

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxTrigger")
search_bar.send_keys("laptopuri")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

main = None

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container"))
    )
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")

except:
    driver.quit()

items = main.find_element_by_id("card_grid")
products = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")
count = 0

for product in products:
    raw_name = WebDriverWait(product, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.card-body.product-title-zone"))
    ).text

    raw_price = WebDriverWait(product, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product-new-price"))
    )

    #Parsing the product name

    raw_name = raw_name.replace("Laptop", "")
    raw_name = raw_name.strip()
    if raw_name.startswith("Apple"):
        sEnd = raw_name.find(",")
    else:
        sEnd = raw_name.find("cu") - 1
    product_name = raw_name[:sEnd]


    #Parsing the product price

    raw_price = raw_price.text[:raw_price.text.find(" ")]
    print(raw_price)
    count += 1

print(f"{count} results returned")
driver.quit()
```

Code works perfectly fine sometimes,but sometimes i get the error:
[image]

Please note i am new at this,so an explanation would be very appreciated.I just learned how to use selenium and the reason i transitioned from beautifulsoup because of the lack of wait possibility,and now when trying to use that,i get this error SOMETIMES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)
```

and how have you used it here :

```
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container"))
    )
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")
```

If you pay attention you would see that, you are using `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` and passing `driver` reference.

**But here**

```
 raw_name = WebDriverWait(product, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.card-body.product-title-zone"))
    ).text
```

you are passing `product` in `WebDriverWait`, which is **wrong**, you should pass `driver` reference here. like

```
raw_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.card-body.product-title-zone"))
        ).text
```

This should help you past this issue for sure.

also, make changes here

```
raw_price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "product-new-price"))
    )
```

This is what we have internally :

```
class WebDriverWait(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, timeout, poll_frequency=POLL_FREQUENCY, ignored_exceptions=None):
        """Constructor, takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds.
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[contains(@class,'close')]/parent::button[@class='close']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'js-accept')]")))).click().perform()

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxTrigger")
search_bar.send_keys("laptopuri")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

main = None

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container")))
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")

except:
    driver.quit()

items = main.find_element_by_id("card_grid")
products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")
count = 0

for product in products:
    raw_name = product.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.card-body.product-title-zone a").text
    print(raw_name)

    raw_price = product.find_element_by_css_selector("p.product-new-price").text
    print(raw_price)

    #Parsing the product name

    # raw_name = raw_name.replace("Laptop", "").strip()
    # if raw_name.startswith("Apple"):
    #     sEnd = raw_name.find(",")
    # else:
    #     sEnd = raw_name.find("cu") - 1
    # product_name = raw_name[:sEnd]


    #Parsing the product price

    # raw_price = raw_price[raw_price.find(" ")]
    # print(raw_price)
    # count += 1

#print(f"{count} results returned")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: No because i want to search for the raw_name in every item in the products list,if i pass the driver as reference i get the same item every time,the first item that selenium finds

Comment: No sir, you can not do that, it should not be done like that, please do as mentioned in the post above, your errors will go away for sure. WebDriverWait `Constructor, takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds`

Comment: What is your final goal ? I think we worked on this ticket yesterday also right ?

Comment: there are multiple div tags and i wanna get the info from each of them,thats why i saved them in the list "products" and now im trying to go through it

Comment: The list products has like 60 div tags in it and i wanna get info out of every tag

Comment: There are multiple div tags of the same class,each representing a product,and i simply wanna get info out of each product like name,price,etc

Comment: okay I can do it using xpath, are you ready to accept solution with xpath ?

Comment: @DragosCiupe : I could do it using css itself, see above few of your css were not correct, I corrected them. Also I do not have what you are doing after scraping the `raw_name` and `raw_price`, if you see the updated 1 section above, you should get 60 records

Comment: But if I leave it like this,won't I get a nosuchelement exception sometimes?for raw name and price

Comment: You can wrap for each loop inside try and except to handle exception, Will you need help on that as well ?

Comment: i wont but the problem is,those elements are aways there,and i want to retrive them all the time,but sometimes i get a nosuchelement exception

Comment: hmmm.. better to have them in try except, cause that is what try is meant for right ? Run the script for at least 5 times and see how many times it breaks.

Comment: So, to clarify my problem,raw name and raw price are always there,the page always has them,but sometimes,i get a nosuchelement exception.My question exactly,how do i retrive them every time?Because i need them

Comment: i get the error because sometimes they arent loaded right?so how do i wait for them?Only for the elements with that class,that are in the items list,not on the entire page

Comment: if i put `raw_name = product.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.card-body.product-title-zone a")` in a try except,if it doesnt load the program continues,but i need the raw_name every time

Comment: We are retrieving text from this list of web elements `products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")` and if you are 100% sure that everytime we go to that page and there will be 60 items then you can put if condition  with  len() function. Also when we write `driver.find_element` it usage implicit waits, so we have the waiting in place.

Comment: Ok,but doesn't `driver` here represent the whole page?i want `products` to be only the elements in the `items` list

Comment: Sure,i will upvote you but,one last try to clarrify my question.I have the whole page,then i retrive the `items` list,as seen in my code above.Then,how do i wait ONLY for the elements in the `items` list,not in the whole page,because `products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")` gets the elements with this class form the entire page,but i want only the elements with this class from the `items` list alone,and wait for them `products = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")`,but if i do this,the program doesnt wait for them

Comment: use explicit waits in that case `products = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.card-item.js-product-data")))`

Comment: also `presence_of_all_elements_located` will return a list of web elements like `find_elements` does.

Comment: And when i do this,i will get back the elements with the css selector `div.card-item.js-product-data` from the entire page,not from the `items` list alone,that's what im trying to tell you

Comment: Item is not a list, it's a single web element. We do not need item at all from your code, since the above mentioned css represent all the web elements that you ve been looking for